# Direct3D Image Brush

Tags: c#, wpf, direct3d

When i finally found how to render a few squares in Direct3D, i then went to find how i apply an image to it instead of a solid color... So I am trying to place an image as a texture on the flat surface... Here is my code and some screen shots...

```
        private void DrawTerrain(float Max_X, float Max_Y)
    {
        ModelVisual3D visual = new ModelVisual3D();// Visual
        Model3DGroup group = new Model3DGroup();// Group

        GeometryModel3D mod = new GeometryModel3D();// Model
        MeshGeometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();// Mesh

        PointLight light = new PointLight() { Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0), Position = new Point3D(1, 1, -1), Range = 3 };// Light

        DiffuseMaterial Mat = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0)));// This is the solid Color brush that works (Screen Shot 1)
        DiffuseMaterial Material = new DiffuseMaterial(new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Image.png"))));// This is the image brush that does nothing (Screen Shot 2) (Image Path is a placeholder, this is an absolute path in the code when testing it)


        for (var Y = 0; Y < Max_Y; Y++)
        {
            for (var X = 0; X < Max_X; X++)
            {
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(X, Y, 0));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(X, Y + 1, 0));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(X + 1, Y, 0));

                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(X, Y + 1, 0));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(X + 1, Y + 1, 0));
                mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(X + 1, Y, 0));
            }
        }

        mod.Geometry = mesh;
        mod.Material = Material;

        group.Children.Add(mod);
        group.Children.Add(light);
        visual.Content = group;
        _Table.Children.Add(visual);
    }
```

[Color Brush Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAAOk.png)
[Image Brush Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxQ7d.png)

What would i change `DiffuseMaterial Material = new DiffuseMaterial(new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Image.png"))));// Meterial` with or am i doing it wrong?

Edit: I am trying to solve this issue without the image being compiled with the app as each user that uses this app will have their own resources. It needs to be fully dynamic

Comment: `Image.png` should be an assembly resource file, i.e. part of your Visual Studio project, with Build Action set to Resource. Then you would load it by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#resource-file-pack-uris) like `"pack://application:,,,/Image.png"`.

Comment: Due to what i am making i cant have the image compiled as a resource because it is all user defined... Is there any other ways that i can do that without it being a Application Resource?

Comment: Load it from a valid local file URL, i.e. a valid absolute or relative path. Just "Image.png" is not enough unless the file is in the current working directory.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help

Comment: So, the image.png was actually a placeholder... if i replace it with a fill URI does your answer change?